# Xpath based on sibling text value

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

Please help me in finding the xpath on the below image. I need to select the Image : Checkmark circle (2,0) based on View : number (0,0) text value

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Post `html` code

Comment: How to get the html code?

Comment: @bibinjoy the website you are testing, press `f12`, find what elements you need and post them here

Comment: This is not a Web Application. It is an Android Application

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Greg Burghardt. Please help me in finding a solution for this.

Comment: I suggest you to use **appium desktop inspector**. It shows you the xpath, id or automation id if any.

Comment: Yes its displaying but not based on the attribute present in (0,0) coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Used following in the xpath and the issue got resolved